# What are the fundamental differences between garbage collection in C# and Java?

Tags: c#, java, garbage-collection

I had some very wrong sounding advice recently from a "senior" developer/coworker regarding the C# garbage collector such as...

- "You need to use destructors
  everywhere in C# because the garbage
  collector cannot be relied upon."
- "The C# garbage collector cannot be
  thought of like the Java garbage
  collector".

This sounds extremely fishy to me, as far as I know the differences between the C# and Java garbage collectors are as follows...

- The C# is a Generational garbage
  collector, Java is concurrent mark
  sweep in 1.6 with G1 being the new
  default (generational) garbage
  collector featuring  Java 7 and has
  been optional since ~1.6.21.  As far
  as I know
- C# as a language has the ability to
  manually dispose of objects that
  implement `IDisposable`.  Java must
  always use garbage collection,
  although some frameworks like SWT
  require you manually call methods to
  release memory in the underlying
  native code.

I realize that Java and C# are just the languages and the garbage collectors are a component of the runtime, however for this case I am specifically speaking about the Sun/Oracle JVM and the Microsoft .NET Runtime.

Does anybody have feedback?

Comment: Your coworker is completely wrong about destructors. Quoting Microsoft's Framework Design Guidelines: "You really don't want to write a finalizer if you can help it."

Comment: I'm afraid your coworker is very wrong.  A finalizer isn't even really a destructor -- it's not a way to manually deallocate a managed object instance.  In fact, if you have a finalizer, it's called by the Garbage Collector.  Finalizers exist to let you clean up unmanaged memory -- like if you made a WinAPI call and got a handle back -- the GC can't collect unmanaged memory like handles, you could use a finalizer for that (although with .Net 2.0 and up, you would probably go with a SafeHandle instead).

Comment: I have to disagree about GC being unreliable.  We've been developing with .Net since 2001, including web apps, and some windows services (the windows services can run for months, and typically only restart when a Windows Update requires a reboot).
the only "leaks" I have ever seen fall into 2 buckets:  mostly cases where we kept a reference (a bug in our code), and a few cases where our code was calling unmanaged code (old C++ DLL, or Winapi, etc), and there was a leak in the unmanaged code (the GC can't help you with unmanaged memory)

Comment: An interesting thing to notice is that there's also a [finalizer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) in Java.

Comment: java has had generational gc for ages.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The advice you've been given is, broadly speaking, a load of hooey.

Both C# and Java have GCs that attempt to optimise the fast recovery of lots of small objects. They're designed to solve the same problem, they do it in slightly different ways but as a user the technical differences in your approach to using them is minimal, even non-existent for the majority of users.

`IDisposable` is nothing to do with the GC as such. It's a standard way of naming methods that would otherwise be called `close`, `destroy`, `dispose`, etc., and often are called that in Java. There is a proposal for Java 7 to add something very similar to the `using` keyword that would call a similar `close` method.

"Destructors" in C# refers to finalizers - this was done deliberately to confuse C++ programmers. :) The CLR spec itself calls them finalizers, exactly as the JVM does.

There are many ways in which Java and C#/CLR differ (user value types, properties, generics and the whole family of related features known as Linq), but the GC is one area where you can develop a substantial amount of software before you need to worry much about the difference between them.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `IDisposable` has nothing to do with a garbage collection. That is an extremely common misconception.

Comment: Oh, tell me about it! I've spent hours on this site trying to explain that not *everything* that implements `IDisposable` needs to also have a finalizer. e.g. anything that merely aggregates other `IDisposables`. Or the objects generated by `yield return` methods. Or anything with a destructor in C++/CLI. Or any class that doesn't want to handle calls from a random thread. The MSDN document aggravates this misunderstanding in lots of ways.

Answer (score 3):

He's backwards on destructors. You need to **not** use destructors in C# unless vital. And if you do use them, you should call SuppressFinalize() if you know the object is in a state where the destructor code is no longer needed (most often because the same clean-up happened in a call to IDisposable.Dispose(). If an object has a destructor and SuppressFinalize has not been called, it will live longer (so that it can have that destructor called).

The Garbage Collector most certainly can be relied upon. It can't be relied upon to call a destructor, or to do so within a certain amount of time, but that's not a matter of it not being reliable, it's a matter of it being reliable in collecting garbage which is its job!

I don't know much about the Java Garbage Collector, and I have no doubt that he's right in saying they can't be thought of like each other when you're getting down to the finer details, though I would hope for the sake of Java coders that it can be thought of like the .NET one most of the time - which is to not think of it at all, generally you don't have to.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid your coworker is incorrect, but don't take my word for it.  Lets have a link fest!

Here are some good articles on GC:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985010.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/bb985011.aspx

Also, Maoni's WebLog has some great stuff (will bring you up to date as well, since the articles above are quite old):
[Link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/author/maoni/)

Also, just this week, Raymond Chen is doing a series on GC:
[Link](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20100813-00/?p=13153)

Here's a good discussion on using Dispose and Finalization:
http://www.bluebytesoftware.com/blog/2005/04/08/DGUpdateDisposeFinalizationAndResourceManagement.aspx

Comment: It would be helpful to get small summaries of points that stand out to support your statement, for each link.